# Collection is empty

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm basically trying to retrieve all "favourites" for a specific user from the pivot table `favourite` (yes it seems that I started my project by misspelling the word favorite).

So when viewing `u/Admin`, I should be able to view all games admin has favorited.

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    $favourites = Auth::user()->favourites;
    // dd($favourites);
    return view('u.index', compact('favourites'));
}
```

But when `dd($favourite);`, I'm returned a empty collection.

```
Collection {#216 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

in m y `Users.php` i have the following:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}

public function favourites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'favourites', 'user_id', 'game_slug')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

Might it have something to do with that `Game.php` has it route key set to the `slug`?

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Comment: please print Auth::user() and check,  are you getting favourites data from user table ?

Comment: Yes I get the user when I `dd(Auth::user())`. The favourites data comes from the `favourites` table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a model called 'Favourite'(make sure you have a user_id column in the favourites table)
- put this in your controller -> use App\Favourite;

And try this code:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$favourites = Favourite::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```